# Instantiation of ViewControllers from storyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a `UIViewController` that looks a bit like this:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, ... { 
    ...

    convenience init(name: String) {
        print("Init with student: \(name)")
        self.init()
    }
    ...
}
```

I have a corresponding Storyboard layout for this, embedded in a UINavigationViewController, linked to a UITabBarController. This seemed like the easiest way to design the layout, and is great for when there's only one instance of this VC required (which is how the app was originally designed).

I'd now like to create multiple tabs from this single design (between 1 and 3), and pass the VC init information programatically, but I'm unsure exactly of the best way to do this - as you can see above I've added a convenience init function based on some reading I've done as that seemed like a good place to start.

It's easy enough to create new named tabs based on the storyboard layout like this:

```
for user in (users)! {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileNC") 
     controller.tabBarItem.title = user.name
     newTabs?.insert(controller, at: 0)
}
self.viewControllers = newTabs
```

But, doing it this way I don't get to call the init function to pass the `UIViewController` the information it needs to display correctly.

How can I create my ViewControllers, link the layout to the Storyboard and use the custom init function? Is this even possible?

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated!!

Comment: Just to understand, why you want call your custom init when you create your UIViewController. I mean what is the constraint that forces you to create a custom initializer ?

Comment: Following @Paulw11's answer I've figured out that I can just instantiate the NC, get the child VC, cast as `ProfileViewController` and then set the variable directly, which seems like a sensible approach - or at least it's working so far! I was originally thinking that ViewDidLoad would be called before I'd set the variable, so I'd need to use a custom Init - but on reflection that was a bit silly; the View is not the same as the Class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a storyboard you cannot use a custom initialiser. You will need to either set the property directly or use a configuration function on the view controller instance after you have created it.